# How to get an c# script Azure function to read a file from C drive, write to blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need a c# script Azure function to read a file from the C drive, and write it to a blob storage account. I think I have some understanding of how to write the file, but how do I read it?

I'm a powershell guy trying to understand functions, go easy on me! I'm imagining a web page which allows selection of a file on the C drive, containing something like:

```
<label for="Image">Select the image file to upload: </label><input type="file" name="Image" />.
```

The user selects a file then clicks a link which is an http trigger for an Azure function which uploads the file to a blob storage account.

If that's reasonable, I need to get the function to read the file on the C drive. I've read some c# guides and I'm trying to use c# script because it seems to be less of a learning curve than c#. I've had a little bit of progress by copying code from the demo http trigger function, and adding some code I've found googling. So for example this code writes some text to a blob:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//added by me
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, TextWriter myOutputBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // I think we're using the Namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
    myOutputBlob.Write(name);

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

I think I'll need to change the type of myOutputBlob to stream, I think I'll probably be able to muddle my way through writing the stream to a blob, but I can't understand how to read the file on the C drive.

For example I think the HttpRequest class (for the req parameter) that I copied from the demo is from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace but this seems to have only a few methods and properties, and nothing that I could see which looked like it was going to read a file on my C drive.

I'd be grateful for any explanations, any code, anything to get me further along. Please remember that I won't understand something aimed at a c# developer level person!

If it's relevant, here's my function.json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "myOutputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "myfolder/myBlob-%myValue%-{rand-guid}.txt",
      "connection": "",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When you say "C Drive" ,From Azure function are you trying to access some sort of network share path ?

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT yes, either a network share or the C drive on the computer of the person who's filling in a form on the web site I'm trying to make. The user will select the file and click a link to trigger the function, which will read the file from the C drive or network share, and upload it to blob storage. That's the plan anyway...

Comment: @aberdeenangus The Function app sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445).

This article mentions it under Restricted Outgoing Ports: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox.

Comment: Suppose It's not your function read your c driver file, it's your web read your file then call your HTTP trigger function with the file binary or stream request.

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT thank you both! Yes what a donkey I am, expecting some code running on a MS VM miles away to be able to access my laptop's C drive. I will try to understand more about how a web page could read the file from my C drive then call the function's http trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Azure Function with a C# sample code for the use case that you mentioned, however, i can connect you to someone who can help. Please PM me.

Have you also considered using Azure data factory to copy data to/from Azure Blob Storage? Alternatively, you can evaluate [this solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage).

Aung Oo, Microsoft Azure Storage Engineering

Comment: how do I PM you? I can't see anything to click on to do that, and I've googled and read that Stackoverflow doesn't have a PM facility.